# show name instead of id in a url using laravel routing

Tags: laravel, routes

I have defined a route in laravel 4 that looks like so :

```
Route::get('/books/{id}', 'HomeController@showBook');
```

in the url It shows /books/1 for example , now i'm asking is there a way to show the name of the book instead but to keep also the id as a parameter in the route for SEO purposes

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add as many parameters to the url as you like, like this:

```
Route::get('/books/{id}/{name}', 'HomeController@showBook');
```

Now when you want to create an url to this page you can do the following:

```
URL::action('HomeController@showBook', ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'My awesome book']);
```

**Update:**

If you are certain that there will never be two books with the same title, you can just use the name of the book in the url. You just need to do this:

```
Route::get('/books/{name}', 'HomeControllers@showBook');
```

In your `showBook` function you need to get the book from the database using the `name` instead of the `id`. I do strongly encourage to use both the id and the name though because otherwise you can get in trouble because I don't think the book name will always be unique.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I want to do exactly .. In the url bar , I don't want to have a url that looks /books/1  rather /book/name-of-book . Does your answer do the job ?

Comment: I really prefer to not do it this way , I would like to stick with the id as a parameter to find the book from the database . but show its name in the url bar

Comment: If you don't want to show the id in the address bar, you can't just find the id out of thin air. You need to find the book by it's name.

Comment: I think there should be a solution to send the id as a parameter to the action but show its name in the address bar . Laravel is so flexible to offer this functionality .. just need to get lucky to find it out

Comment: It's just not possible in a http request to add the id in any other way, you only have the data that the url gives you. So laravel won't be able to do this. The only other options you can try is to send the id's via post data, but then you need a form for every link, or add them to the url using query strings, but these are not SEO friendly at all.

Comment: Keep the ID parameter and add Name as an optional one. That way you would have `books/1/Im_A_Programmer` or `books/1/` taking you to the same page. Append the route parameter with a `?` to make it optional.

Comment: Ok I give up and I marked your answer as the solution even if I knew it before ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could also do something like this:

```
Route::get('books/{name}', function($name){
    $url = explode("-", $name);
    $id = $url[0];
    return "Book #$id";
});
```

So you can get book by id if you pass an url like: `http://website.url/books/1-book-name`

Answer (score 1):

if your using laravel 8, this may be helpfull.
In your Controller add this

```
public function show(Blog $blog)
{
    return view('dashboard.Blog.show',compact('blog'));
}
```

In your web.php add this

```
Route::get('blog/{blog}', [\App\Http\Controllers\BlogController::class,'show'])->name('show');
```

Then add this to your model (am using Blog as my Model)

```
 public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'title'; // db column name you would like to appear in the url.
}
```

**Note:** Please let your column name be unique(good practice).
**Result:** http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/HelloWorld .....url for a single blog
**So no more http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/1**
You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use model binding [check more on laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#customizing-the-default-key-name)

For example

```
Route::get('book/{book:name}',[BookController::class,'getBook'])->name('book');
```

The **name** attribute in `"book/{book:name}"` should be unique.